# Do 'executable' file systems exist?

Tags: filesystems, executable

Are there any Unix/Linux filesystems that do the following?

1. if the file is executable, return a virtual file containing the `stdout` generated by executing it (it would have to be non-writable, I suppose);
2. otherwise behave the same as ext4 and friends and provide the file itself.

I recently had a situation where I couldn't pipe information into a process but had to pass a (multiline) file as an option. Being able to generate that file on the fly (locally or over the network) seemed to me to be an elegant alternative.

Creating a file on /tmp was not an option because the option in question was in an attribute of an LDAP entry. My LDAP entry contains an attribute value somewhat like the following, which is statically defined:

```
-fstype=cifs...,rw,credentials=FILENAME,... ://remote
```

This is passed as data to a process that evaluates it and expects a FILENAME as a parameter to the `credentials=` option. There is no Bash or any other script. And I have no way that I am aware of of creating a /tmp file on the fly in LDAP.

Please don't ask *why* I want to do it: I solved my problem with a work-around, but I'm still interested in the fundamental question.

Of course, there is always the bonus question that goes with this sort of thing: can it be done safely?

Steve

Comment: How abut Bash process substitution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that you have a utility that demands a file _name_ to read, and you wish to produce that "file" on the fly instead of having it actually on the filesystem? Also, I wonder, why is creating a temporary file in `/tmp` out of the question; and what do LDAP attributes have to do with that?

Comment: I've created to clarify the question by adding some text to the original question. and yes, I do wish to produce a file on the fly in place of the execuatble on the filesystem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1211877/432690

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That looks very much like what I was looking for! Would you write it up as an answer please, so I can credit you.

Comment: I won't. IMO my answer under the linked question is of mediocre quality. It only points in some directions which I haven't even tested. I don't want to repeat such an answer here. But if you manage to build and configure a working solution then please you post an answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, ok, I added a link to scriptfs to my answer with your name on it. you can edit it out if you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's see if I got this right: You have some data in LDAP, that refers to some filename (among other things). Presumably that file is on some network share readable by all the hosts using that LDAP directory, and you'd like the contents of the file to be created dynamically. So, e.g. the directory contains `credentials=/ldap/foo.cred`, and when some system opens `/ldap/foo.cred`, they get the dynamic data.

There appears to be a program called [ScriptFS](https://github.com/frodonh/scriptfs), a [FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) implementation of pretty much exactly what you ask, but I'm not familiar with the tool, and don't know how well it works. (@KamilMaciorowski mentioned this in a comment and in their [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1211877/linux-interpreted-on-read-ala-php-for-local-files) on superuser.)

> ScriptFS is a new file system which merely replicates a local file system, but replaces all files detected as "scripts" by the result of their execution.

FUSE, like the name implies, allows a userspace program to implement a filesystem, like any other, and the kernel arranges for file access requests to go to the process responsible for dealing with the filesystem. This would allow arbitrary dynamic content to be generated. Presumably, it would also work over network shares, since the files appear as regular files, but I have no personal experience of using it.

Out of the more "traditional" features, the ones that get close are named pipes and named sockets.

Named pipes created with `mkfifo` are like the pipes you use when you do `somecmd | grep foo`, except that they have a name in the filesystem and can be opened from there. So you could write `mkfifo p; somecmd > p & grep foo < p`. Or similarly the reader could open it first. Both readers and writers block until there's someone at the other end. At first, this seems like it could do what you want, you could arrange for a program to write at the pipe, and give the current output when someone opens it for reading. However, pipes only exist once, so concurrent users would attach to the same stream. Also, I have absolutely no idea how they work over network shares. It's possible that the pipe will exist only on the client side, so both ends will need to be on the same system.

Unix domain sockets can also exist with a name in the filesystem (if you're running systemd, you can probably find a few under `/run`). When connected to, the opening process is connected to the process listening on the socket (as with a TCP connection). The connections here are independent, but the catch is that (AFAIK) Unix domain sockets can't be opened with `open()`, but need to be connected to with `connect()`. Hence, you can't do `cat < socket`, it won't work.

Comment: It is strange that the second paragraph says "this does not exist", while the final paragraph notes that *exactly* this exists.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, it said "I don't _think_ it exists"! ;) edited.

Answer (score 0):

No. And such a file system would be quite useless.

For example: if `sed` would be on that filesystem, how  would `ls | sed 's/a/b'` work? The shell would open `sed` for execution, but the file system would return STDOUT of `sed` instead. However, the filesystem does not have a STDIN for `sed`, so, now everything hangs (`sed` waiting for STDIN) or exits (empty STDIN for `sed`) without doing anything.

It is also an XY problem.

You should not attempt to solve scripting problems with altering the filesystem behavior.

As  @Arkadiusz Drabczyk suggested, your problem would have been solved with process substitution. As an example: if you would want to do

```
sort file1 | uniq >tmp1
sort file2 | uniq >tmp2
diff tmp1 tmp2
```

but you cannot or do not want to create temp-files `tmp1` and `tmp2`, you can

```
diff <(sort file1 | uniq) <(sort file2 | uniq)
```

An additional example, that would look a bit like your question: Suppose I have a file `inputfile` with:

```
a:b:c:d
i:j:k:l
e:f:g:h
```

and I have a simple demonstration script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(echo $* | sed 's/.*credentials=//;s/,.*//')
echo "The filename is: $filename"
echo "The contents is:"
cat $filename
```

Then, obviously, I could:

```
./procsub.sh -fstype=cifs...,rw,credentials=inputfile,,... ://remote
```

and the output would be:

```
a:b:c:d
i:j:k:l
e:f:g:h
```

However, I could also, if I wanted the output sorted for example, do:

```
./procsub.sh -fstype=cifs...,rw,credentials=<(sort inputfile),,... ://remote
```

and then the output would be:

```
The filename is: /dev/fd/63
The contents is:
a:b:c:d
e:f:g:h
i:j:k:l
```

Hope that clarifies a bit more.

Comment: Obviously there would be limitations on its use: as I said, the resultant file why be read-only; and the executable wouldn’t be able to read stdin.

Comment: How does one do process substitution in the middle of a static text defined in an LDAP attribute? In that context I have no access to any scripting language, just the possibility of naming a file parameter.

Comment: @StephenWinnall it would help if you gave complete details about the system and programs you're using. Your idea of an "executable filesystem" sounds like complete overkill. Even when dealing with ornery proprietary programs, you can use some wrapper or some `LD_PRELOAD` hack (e.g. to turn `fopen` into `popen`) instead of doing some FUSE filesystem of other complicated stuff.

Comment: @user414777 I already have a work-around for my problem. I was just interested to know whether anyone knew of such a filesystem. I’ve been using Unix (albeit in a dilletante fashion) since 1985 and have never heard of such a thing. That is why I came here rather than to Server Fault. I’m not looking for alternative solutions: I was just asking the question “does such a filesystem exist”?

Comment: @StephenWinnall If that was the question, the answer is still no, it does not exist. The closest you get is the process substitution files under `/dev/fd`.

Comment: @ljm dullaart  Thanks, but I have absolutely no access to the executable context in which the LDAP attribute is used. As I wrote above, I am not looking for alternative solutions but just asking whether there is such a thing as an ‘executable filesystem’.

Comment: @StephenWinnall you can "easily" write such a filesystem with FUSE. But as I said, it's much easier (and cleaner) to do everything on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically what you describe doesn't make a lot of sense - it would be relatively simple to build with FUSE - but it just seems wrong on so many levels.

You want to be able to read potentially dynamic data from a file because that's the only thing a program which you can't modify will source the data from. That can be solved with a filesystem pipe:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 PIPE="/tmp/credentials"
 if [ ! -p "$PIPE" ] ; then
    mkfifo "$PIPE"
 fi

 do
    echo $SECRET >$PIPE
 done
```

Comment: I can see that it doesn’t appeal to scripting gurus ;-) But what about a context where you have no access to scripts or other executables? I don’t actually know which executable reads my LDAP attribute, and I have no way of interceding in how it reads it.